# "BAD_ALLOC Memory" PSI on ENVI

Tags: raster, envi

I'm currently working on S1-images, and I want to process PSI on them. I use ENVI 5.5 with SarScape.

Here are the steps I followed :

- I opened 23+1 images (Import Data) and I cropped them using SAR sampling function. I used orbit files.
- Step1 - Connection Graph, everything seems OK.
- Step2 - Interferogram Processing. There I use a DEM downloaded on USGS website (SRTM 35sec).

Unfortunately, I got the message error : "Memory BAD_ALLOC (-1.0)". On my computer, I have 1To space, and 16Go RAM. I'm on Windows 7, 64bits. 
I tried many things to solve this problem :

- Modify the AOI, down to pwr files measuring less than 8MB
- Modify the DEM (using the DEM provided by SNAP)
- Select less images (just to check) and the same error appears.

I did not find any solution to solve this problem. I know this seems like a memory problem, but even with very small images I got the issue. I did not find any piece of solution.

Did someone already have this problem ? Have you any ideas on how I can solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem. Here was the solution :

- Download SRTM file on USGS website : https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/
- Put the file in the default directory for SRTM (change it in SARSCAPE > Preferences)
- Once in step 2 of the PSI process, click on download DEM file, then on SRTM 3 version 1, and search on the area, with the output projection as "GLOBAL" or "UTM"
- It will automatically find the DEM and open it
- Launch STEP 2

The problem came from the opening of the DEM file. The DEM was correct, but the format created led to the error.